# <a> with PHP within splits the link

Tags: php, links, split

I've finally found out how to call a the project-type in a link so the link changes depending on which page it shows.

This is the code:

```
    <h3 class="widget-title">
<a href="../">Terug naar <?php the_terms($post->ID, 'fluxus-project-type'); ?></a></h3>
```

But what happens now is the following.

Both 'Terug naar' and the result from ID, 'fluxus-project-type'); ?> get split.

Example is found on the left side of the page at: http://www.jeroenbrugman.com/portfolio/schilderijen/sickert-als-jack/

Terug naar and Schilderijen are split in 2. How can I combine those so it's one link?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing isn't ever going to work the way you want. `the_terms()` is going to produce a list of complete `a` tags so you can't nest or merge it with another one like you are trying to do. And there are [no convenient arguments or filters](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1438) that would allow you to alter that link text. There are some not-so-convenient ones though. The simplest is a filter on `get_the_terms`

```
function prefix_term_name($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
  foreach ($terms as &$term) {
    $term->name = 'Terug naar '.$term->name;
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

Which you would use like:

```
?>
<h3 class="widget-title"><?php
  add_filter( 'get_the_terms','prefix_term_name',10,3);
  the_terms($post->ID, 'fluxus-project-type'); 
  remove_filter( 'get_the_terms','prefix_term_name',10,3); ?>
</h3><?php
```

The function definition itself can be in your `functions.php` file to keep things neat.
    }

Comment: I don't think you understand what i want lol. I'm probably unclear.  What i want: <a href="../"> Terug naar (insert project-type) here</a>  I thought i was able to produce this with the code in my OP. But it shows 2 different hyperlinks now.

Comment: Then clarify. It makes no sense to try to "combine" those elements into a single link in the way that you are doing because `the_terms()` will potentially (and usually) produce multiple links. If you run that code, you will find that "Terug naar Schilderijen" are a single link which seems to be what you asked for.

Comment: A relative link-- aka `../`-- is not going to work reliably within WordPress, if it works at all.

Comment: I added your first code to my themes function.php and the second code on the artwork page. But putting the first code in my function.php breaks my whole site..

Comment: I missed a closing `}` when I pasted the code over. See the edit.

Comment: Ow sorry. My bad. I could atleast checked that. Now it works. But the link isn't showing? Do I still need to call the link?

Comment: `the_terms()` should `echo`. See the sample code I provided.

Comment: Im so sorry. Im such a pain in the @$$. Got it. Your second code had to go above the <a>